# How to render one React Native component after another component had rendered?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Let's say I have 2 components `A` and `B`. I want to render component `A` and after that render component `B`. To make that more obvious, I would also like to set some delay (let's say 2 seconds) between the rendering of `A` and `B`. What would be the best way to approach this? I guess I should somehow trigger the rendering of `B` in the `componentDidMount` of `A`, but I don't really know how to do that triggering.

Thanks :)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very vague and open to multiple implementation.
Here's my take:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = { displayComponentB: false }
    this.displayComponentB = this.displayComponentB.bind(this)
  }
  displayComponentB() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ displayComponentB: true })
    }, 2000) // delay
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ComponentA onComponentDidMount={this.displayComponentB}/>
        {
          this.state.displayComponentB && 
          <ComponentB />
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export class ComponentA extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onComponentDidMount && this.props.onComponentDidMount()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.component, styles.componentA]}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Component A</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Full code and live demo: https://snack.expo.io/SkIOLJ3eM

Comment: The state change would cause re-rendering of `A` with `B` included. Can I avoid the re-rendering?

Also here I simplified the problem to have only 2 views. What if I want to have an array of components and want to define the order in which they would be rendered? This is a completely different question, but I would like to know if there is a solution which doesn't re-render the `A` component in the question.

Comment: Yes, how do do it without re-rendering

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. Why would you want to avoid the re-rendering if the state change?

Comment: I think one should either use pure components or shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle methods to resolve the re-rendering

Answer (score 2):

use setTimeout in componentDidMount.

here is a sample

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        isBVisible:false
    };
}

componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({isBVisible:true});
    }, 2000);
}

render(){
    return(<View>
        <View style={{width:100,height:100,backgroundColor:"red"}}/>
        {this.state.isBVisible ? <View style={{width:100,height:100,backgroundColor:"green"}}/>:null}
    </View>)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, the `B` view in my case would be a custom defined component with its own render() method. I am not sure how to trigger that render method dynamically.

Comment: @giliev render will be called only when initilized and  call setState. in the sample, the parent component of B trigger re-render when setState, it will make render function of B called