# How to control the order of rendering components in React?

Tags: reactjs

There is a page contains a booking list and a popup window(A modal with survey questions). To reduce the impact on booking list loading time, I want to render the modal component after the booking list be completely loaded.

ps.there are network data request in both `<BookingList/>` and `<Modal/>`.

How should I do with React?

Thanks for help.

```js
export default function Body() {
  return (
    <>
      <BookingList .../>
      <Modal .../>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: This can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47547465/how-to-render-one-react-native-component-after-another-component-had-rendered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can conditionally render the Modal component after the `BookingList` fetches the results.
For that, you'd need a state variable in the parent component of `BookingList` and `Modal`. Code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-cookies-zrpit

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";

const BookingList = ({ setLoadedBookingList }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoadedBookingList();
    }, 1000);
  }, [setLoadedBookingList]);

  return <h2>BookingList</h2>;
};

const Modal = () => <h1>Modal</h1>;

export default function App() {
  const [loadBookingList, setLoadBookingList] = useState(false);

  const setLoadedBookingList = useCallback(() => {
    setLoadBookingList(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BookingList setLoadedBookingList={setLoadedBookingList} />
      {loadBookingList && <Modal />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This works for me! Thanks!

A small question, are these code is necessary?


`const setLoadedBookingList = useCallback(() => { setLoadBookingList(true);}, []);`


I find it work without these code and use `setLoadedBookingList(true)` in BookingList.

Comment: Yes,  it can be done like that as well. React guarantees that setState function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect or useCallback dependency list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use react hooks `useState()` and `useEffect()`:

```
export default function Body() {
  // `isLoaded` is a variable with false as initial value
  // `setLoaded` is a method to modify the value of `isLoaded`
  const [isLoaded, setLoaded] = React.useState(false)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // some method used in loading the resource, 
    // after completion you can set the isLoaded to true
    loadBookingList().then(loaded => setLoaded(true));
  }, 
  // second argument to `useEffect` is the dependency which is out `setLoaded` function
  [setLoaded]);

  return (
    <>
      // conditional rendering based on `isLoaded`
      {isLoaded && <BookingList .../>}
      <Modal .../>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry for unclear question. The `loadBookingList()` function is in `BookingList` components. And the render sequence should be `<BookingList/>(completely loaded) -> <Modal/>`.